# Utf-8 to UTF-16BE

Tags: php, encoding

I save a record "فحص الرسالة العربية" in php that always saved as :

```
&#1601;&#1581;&#1589; &#1575;&#1604;&#1585;&#1587;&#1575;&#1604;&#1577; &#1575;&#1604;&#1593;&#1585;&#1576;&#1610;&#1577;
```

I want to convert this into UTF-16BE chars when i retrieve it so I am using a function that returns :

```
002600230031003600300031003b002600230031003500380031003b002600230031003500380039003b0020002600230031003500370035003b002600230031003600300034003b002600230031003500380035003b002600230031003500380037003b002600230031003500370035003b002600230031003600300034003b002600230031003500370037003b0020002600230031003500370035003b002600230031003600300034003b002600230031003500390033003b002600230031003500380035003b002600230031003500370036003b002600230031003600310030003b002600230031003500370037003b
```

This is function that m using for converting string retrieved from database

```
function convertCharsn($string) {
    $in = '';
    $out = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE', $string);
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($out); $i++) {
      $in .= sprintf("%02X", ord($out[$i]));
    }
    return $in;
}
```

But when i type same character in below url, it shows different characters as compared to my string.
http://www.routesms.com/downloads/onlineunicode.asp

returning :

```
0641062D063500200627064406310633062706440629002006270644063906310628064A0629
```

I want my string to be converted as it is being converted in above url.
my database collation is utf-8_general_ci

Comment: What do you want to store, readable and sortable text or code like "&#1601;&#1581;&#1589;"?

Comment: I want to have "&#1601;&#1581;&#1589; &#1575;&#1604;&#1585;&#1587;&#1575;&#1604;&#1577; &#1575;&#1604;&#1593;&#1585;&#1576;&#1610;&#1577;" into these characters "0641062D063500200627064406310633062706440629002006270644063906310628064A0629
"

Comment: `&$1601;` is not "UTF-8" and `064106...` is not "UTF-16BE". Who is supposed to consume this data and are you sure you're looking for `064106...` as the result instead of actual UTF-16BE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need to decode those characters out of HTML entities first.  Just use [`html_entity_decode()`](http://us.php.net/html_entity_decode)

```
$rawChars = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401, 'UTF-8');

convertCharsn($rawChars);
```

Otherwise, you're just encoding the entities.  You can see that as `&` is `0026` in UTF16, and `#` is `0023`.  So you can see the repeating sequence of `00260023` in the above transcoding that you posted.  So decode it first, and you should be set...